# Other fields depend on checkboxes using jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-chosen

I have a scenario with Chosen plugin and jQuery Validate plugin where I'm trying to show and hide fields according to radio button checked options. So as I'm trying to validate them too. Here's my code:

```
<form id="my-form" action="" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="active" id="1" value="1" onclick="test(1)" > A
<input type="radio" name="active" id="1" value="2" onclick="test(2)"> B
<input type="radio" name="active" id="1" value="3" onclick="test(3)"> C
<input type="radio" name="active" id="1" value="4" onclick="test(4)" checked> D

    <div class='with-select' id="resident" style="display:none !important;">
        <span>resident:</span>
        <select class="chosen-select"  required="true">
            <option value="">[select option]</option>
            <option value="01">Value 1</option>
            <option value="02">Value 2</option>
            <option value="03">Value 3</option>
            <option value="04">Value 4</option>
            <option value="05">Value 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='with-select' id="employee"  style="display:none !important;">
        <span>employee:</span>
        <select class="chosen-select"  name="selEmp" id="selEmp" required="true">
            <option value="">[select option]</option>
            <option value="01">Value 1</option>
            <option value="02">Value 2</option>
            <option value="03">Value 3</option>
            <option value="04">Value 4</option>
            <option value="05">Value 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class='with-select' id="inputvis" style="display:none !important;">
        <span>Visitor:</span>
        <input type="text" name="txtVis" id="txtVis" required="true">
    </div>
    <div class='with-select'  id="inputothr" >
        <span>Other:</span>
        <input type="text" name="txtOther" id="txtOther"  required="true">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    // Chosen validation
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: ":hidden:not(select)" });

// validation of chosen on change
if ($("select.chosen-select").length > 0) {
    $("select.chosen-select").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('required') !== undefined) {
            $(this).on("change", function() {
                $(this).valid();
            });
        }
    });
}

// validation
$('#my-form').validate({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        console.log("placement");
        if (element.is("select.chosen-select")) {
            console.log("placement for chosen");
            // placement for chosen
            element.next("div.chzn-container").append(error);
        } else {
            // standard placement
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

window.test = function(a){
//alert(a);
switch(a){
    case 1:
  $("#resident").show();
  $("#employee").hide();
  $("#inputvis").hide();
  $("#inputothr").hide();
  break;

  case 2:
  $("#resident").hide();
  $("#employee").show();
  $("#inputvis").hide();
  $("#inputothr").hide();
  break;

  case 3:
  $("#resident").hide();
  $("#employee").hide();
  $("#inputvis").show();
  $("#inputothr").hide();
  break;

  case 4:
  $("#resident").hide();
  $("#employee").hide();
  $("#inputvis").hide();
  $("#inputothr").show();
  break;
}
}

</script>
```

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8x03jvr/6/)

The problem is that I have to select/enter values in every field to post the form. How can I post the form with checking one radio button for example, and then enter value in only that field (others) corresponding and skip validation of other select box or whatever left out?

Comment: I think, that fiddle is working as expected. You need one check box selected and based on that checkbox, one more field user need to select.

Comment: My req is if any one field is having value then the form should submit. But here every field is requiring some value to be submitted

Comment: You want only check box selection is mandatory ?

Comment: @sriharsha sorry i don't know what that exactly means?

Comment: Every field that contains a `required="true"` attribute is going to be made as required by jQuery Validate.  What do you expect?

Comment: What does Chosen plugin have to do with this question?   Seems like it would function the same without it, right?

Comment: @Sparky but i want to check for validation only those fields which are visible